# An algebra that is not a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let  ${\cal C} \in P(X)$ which $X$ is a non empty set  and

$${\cal C}=\{A\in P(X);  A \text{ or } A^c= X\smallsetminus A \}$$

Proof that  $\cal{C}$ is a algebra but not a $\sigma$-algebra, and give an example.

I don't see what is the elements of set ${\cal C}$ (Are $A$ only or $A^c$ only or both?), and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: could you explain better the definition of $\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: it is in our textbook, me too I don't undertand it

Comment: I think it's a typo that should instead be ${\cal C}=\{A\in P(X);\  A \text{ or } A^c \text{ is finite }\}$, where $A^c= X\smallsetminus A$ and $X$ is infinite. (They just omitted the "is finite".)

Answer (score 0):

The class  $\mathscr{A}=\{F\subset \mathbb{N}: F \text{ is finite or } F^c \text{ is finite}\} $is an algebra  of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ but not a $\sigma$-algebra. 
The let $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ sets in $\mathscr{A}$, then or every $A$ is finite or at last one $A_i$ is infinite (and therefore A^i^c is finite) so or the union is finite or the complement of the union has finite complement.

Clearly $\mathscr{A}$ is closed to complement.

The union of even numbers do not lies in $\mathscr{A}$, so $\mathscr{A}$ is not a $\sigma$-álgebra.

Comment: When you take F is finite or F^cis finite  is what meant by A or $A^C$

Comment: @MaryMaths I was not capable to understand the definition you give above of $\mathcal{C}$. So I give an example of an algebra which is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: It is in our textbook,me too I don't undertand it, But in general what we search in general case. In others word how do you think to this example?

Comment: I will explain in details in the answer. Could you provide me the name of your textbook?

Comment: It is writen in french http://www.fsr.ac.ma/cours/maths/Ghanmi/Cours-SMA5%2017-18.pdf,  Remarque 1.2.4.

Comment: What you mean by A  is closed to complement. And why do you take even numbers. I don't see what is the goal of the proof